# Dynamic height of the cell is wrong sometimes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UILabel in a cell and I need to change the height of the UILabel dynamically. So the cell is a xib file with height 44 and label 240x44 and label autosizing horizontally and vertically. The font is 15.0f size, system. Number of lines = 0, wrap by word.

So I have the method

```
+ (CGFloat) cellHeightForString: (NSString *) string
{
    CGFloat cellHeight = [string sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(240.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping].height;
    return  cellHeight < 44.0f ? 44.0f : cellHeight;
}
```

but the height of the cell is sometimes smaller so not all lines of the text are shown in the cell. Can't understand what I'm doing wrong.. Any help?

Comment: check the string's font size which was displayed in the table view. I think it is greater than 15!!

Comment: System 15.0 in xib and [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f] in sizeWithFontMethod

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// add your code snippet here
// dynamically change the label height,
       CGSize textSize = {
        200.0,   // limit width
        20000.0  // and height of text area
    };

    CGSize contentSize = [yourText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGFloat contentHeight = contentSize.height < 36? 36: contentSize.height; // lower bound for height

    CGRect labelFrame = [yourLabel frame];
    yourLabel.size.height = contentHeight;
    [yourLabel setFrame: labelFrame];
    [yourLabel setText:yourText];
    return cell;
}
```

Dynamically change the cell height,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    YourCell *currentCell = (YourCell*)[self tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

// change hard coded value based on your cell alignment

    int cellLength=[currentCell.yourLabel.text length]/42;
    cellLength = cellLength*22 > 200 ? cellLength*22 : 200;
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake((200 - 10), cellLength);
    CGSize size1 = [cellText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    return 220+size1.height;
}
```